# PHP preg_match_all/preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a report function for our firewall.
The firewall rules are stored in json format.

Here is a sample of the string.

```
[{"id":1,"enabled":true,"description":"TEMP","matchers":{"javaClass":"java.util.LinkedList","list":[{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1.1.1.1","matcherType":"DST_ADDR"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"80","matcherType":"DST_PORT"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1,3,2","matcherType":"DST_INTF"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"2.2.2.2","matcherType":"SRC_ADDR"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1,2,wan","matcherType":"SRC_INTF"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"UDP,TCP,any","matcherType":"PROTOCOL"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"svrbjgu","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_USERNAME"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"intern-it","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_GROUP"}]},"ruleId":5001,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRule","block":false,"log":true}]
```

And the preg_match_all filter i have:

```
    preg_match_all('/\"description":"(.*?)\","matchers"/',$str,$description);
preg_match_all('/\"id":(.*?)\,"/',$str,$id);
preg_match_all('/\"ruleId":(.*?)\,"/',$str,$rule_id);
preg_match_all('/\"enabled":(.*?)\,"description"/',$str,$enable);
preg_match_all('/\"block":(.*?)\,"/',$str,$block);
preg_match_all('/\"log":(.*?)\}/',$str,$log);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"DST_ADDR"/',$str,$dest_add);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"DST_PORT"/',$str,$dest_port);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"DST_INTF"/',$str,$dest_int);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\,","matcherType":"SRC_ADDR"/',$str,$src_add);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"SRC_INTF"/',$str,$src_int);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"PROTOCOL"/',$str,$protocol);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_USERNAME"/',$str,$user);
preg_match_all('/\"value":"(.*?)\","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_GROUP"/',$str,$group);
```

What happens is that the start for evry matcher is VALUE":" when i print $dest_port i get `"1.1.1.1","matcherType":"DST_ADDR"},`{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"80" instead of just 80.

Any one that have a preg_match_all to find the matchertype first and then read backwords to the "value":"?

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Why not *parse* the JSON with a JSON parser...?

Comment: Use [**json_decode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: I should be able to work with json_decode but it will give me some information that i don't need so i would still have to regex some parts out. 

It might be easyer just to apply filters on the json_decode output.
If i have time i will to some test with it ;)

Comment: @WebFooL I'd still say it is better to have to apply your regex on as small a target as possible, after extraction using `json_decode`.  A lot less could go wrong :)

Comment: Ahh!! 
Why did i not test this at once ;) 
This looks so much better

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

```
$xyz = <<<EOX
[{"id":1,"enabled":true,"description":"TEMP","matchers":{"javaClass":"java.util.LinkedList","list":[{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1.1.1.1","matcherType":"DST_ADDR"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"80","matcherType":"DST_PORT"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1,3,2","matcherType":"DST_INTF"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"2.2.2.2","matcherType":"SRC_ADDR"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1,2,wan","matcherType":"SRC_INTF"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"UDP,TCP,any","matcherType":"PROTOCOL"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"svrbjgu","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_USERNAME"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"intern-it","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_GROUP"}]},"ruleId":5001,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRule","block":false,"log":true}]
EOX;

var_dump(json_decode($xyz)); //execute other operations, iteration etc here
```

This works much better than regex. Returns structured data, you can iterate through.

Comment: I have ended up running json_decode. 

And then manipulating the array from there. 

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using with json_decode.

sample:

```
$jsondata ='[{"id":1,"enabled":true,"description":"TEMP","matchers":{"javaClass":"java.util.LinkedList","list":[{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1.1.1.1","matcherType":"DST_ADDR"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"80","matcherType":"DST_PORT"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1,3,2","matcherType":"DST_INTF"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"2.2.2.2","matcherType":"SRC_ADDR"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"1,2,wan","matcherType":"SRC_INTF"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"UDP,TCP,any","matcherType":"PROTOCOL"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"svrbjgu","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_USERNAME"},{"invert":false,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRuleMatcher","value":"intern-it","matcherType":"DIRECTORY_CONNECTOR_GROUP"}]},"ruleId":5001,"javaClass":"com.untangle.node.firewall.FirewallRule","block":false,"log":true}]';
$data = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo '<table><tr><th WIDTH="10">Nr.</th><th WIDTH="10">RuleID</th><th WIDTH="150">Description</th><th WIDTH="100">Protocol</th><th WIDTH="75">Src Int</th><th WIDTH="150">Src Address</th><th WIDTH="100">Src Port</th><th WIDTH="75">Dest. Int</th><th WIDTH="150">Dest Address</th><th WIDTH="100">Dest. Port</th><th WIDTH="50">Action</th><th WIDTH="50">Log</th><th WIDTH="50">Enabled</th></tr>';
echo "<tr><td>test.</td><td> {$data[0]['ruleId']} </td><td>{$data[0]['description']}</td><td>{$data[0]['enabled']}</td></tr>" ;
```